# How Do I resolve the error message "No handles with labels found to put in legend"

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the loss graph, but I don't know why this error is showing up.

```
modellist = ["RegularConv", "BothConv", "SeparableConv"]
color = ['#1f77b4', '#ff7f0e', '#2ca02c']

for index in range(len(historys)):
    plt.plot(historys[index].history['val_loss'], label=modellist[index], color=color[index])
    
plt.ylabel('Validation Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(loc = 0)
plt.show()
```

This is the error I got:

```
No handles with labels found to put in legend.
```

Comment: How does the plot look like without the call to `plt.legend`?  You didn't provide reproducible test data for the `historys`, making it hard to know what is going on.  The error could e.g. be explained by `historys` being empty. (Note that `loc=0` and `loc='best'` are functioning equally, although the latter is easier to read).